# Simple Python IoC

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I'm looking into having a simple dependency injection container in Python. I've Googled on it but so far the solutions that I've found are quite huge and use constructs such as decorators and so on which I'm not so fond of.

So, inspired (or copying) the [Twittee IoC written by Fabien Potencier in PHP](http://twittee.org) I wrote this script. I'd like to get a review on it

```
class Pymple(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}

    def register(self, key, value, as_singleton=False):
        self._values[key] = value

        if as_singleton:
            self._values[key] = self.resolve(key)

    def resolve(self, key):
        if not key in self._values:
            raise ValueError('Value "%s" is not registered.' % key)

        return self._values[key](self) if callable(self._values[key]) else self._values[key]
```

This could latter be used as

```
class Sum:

    def __ini__():
        pass

    def sum(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class Multiply:
    def __init__(self, sum):
        self.sum = sum

    def multiply(self, a, b):
        rv = 0
        for k in range(0, a):
            rv = self.sum.sum(rv, b)
        return rv

container = Pymple()
container.register('sum', lambda c: Sum(), True)
container.register('multiply', lambda c: Multiply(c.resolve('sum')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect your `Pymple` class to be a bit simpler to use. At least for the retrieval of values something like this:

```
container = Pymple()
container.register('sum', lambda c: Sum(), True)
container.sum.sum(1, 2)  # returns 3
```

or like this:

```
container = Pymple()
container.sum = lambda c: Sum()
container.sum.sum(1, 2)  # returns 3
```

feels more natural to me. You can even provide the two versions, `register` being able to take optional parameters that `__setattr__` can't.

So I would start with something like:

```
class Pymple(object):
    """Some usefull docstring here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('_values', {})

    def register(self, key, value, as_singleton=False):
        self._values[key] = value

        if as_singleton:
            self._values[key] = getattr(self, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.register(key, value, True)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key not in self._values:
            raise AttributeError("'{}' is not registered.".format(key))

        attribute = self._values[key]
        return attribute(self) if callable(attribute) else attribute
```

Note the change in the type of error raised since we are dealing with attributes now. You also need to deal with the modified version of `__setattr__` so you can't directly assign `{}` to `self._values`.

---

Now about the way you return your values… Given the above interface, I am expecting that:

```
def email(container):
    mail = "{c.name}.{c.lastname}@{c.domain}".format(c=container)
    def functor():
        return '[{}] {}'.format(time.time(), mail)
    return functor

container = Pymple()
container.name = lambda c: 'spam'
container.lastname = lambda c: 'eggs'
container.domain = lambda c: 'bacon'
container.frozen_email = email
container.name = lambda c: 'foo'
container.register('email', email)
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
container.domain = lambda c: 'example.org'
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
```

would print:

```
[1479207663.6114736] spam.eggs@bacon
[1479207663.7469463] foo.eggs@bacon
[1479207663.8756231] spam.eggs@bacon
[1479207663.9963526] foo.eggs@example.org
```

However it will fail as, even though `frozen_email` is stored "as a singleton", the callable returned by `email` will be called with the container as argument and it does not expect it.

Two other things that can be observed from this example:

- `as_singleton` is more an `as_constant` than anything else;
- there is too much boilerplate required when storing a constant.

I think that, instead of trying to know if you have stored a constant or a function in the getter, you should wrap your constants into functions taking the container as parameter into the setter. And the getter will blindly perform a function call:

```
class Pymple(object):
    """Some usefull docstring here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('_values', {})

    def register(self, key, value, constant=False):
        if constant:
            self._values[key] = lambda c: value
        else:
            self._values[key] = value

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.register(key, value, True)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key not in self._values:
            raise AttributeError("'{}' is not registered.".format(key))

        return self._values[key](self)
```

And the above example is now:

```
container = Pymple()
container.name = 'spam'
container.lastname = 'eggs'
container.domain = 'bacon'
container.frozen_email = email(container)
container.name = 'foo'
container.register('email', email)
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
container.domain = 'example.org'
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
```

---

Now that we simplified the registration of "constant" values (be they callable or not), let's see if we can't do the same with "variable" ones. For one, `register` offers a way to use your `Pymple` class with existing functions so let's keep it. For two, you can easily use `__setattr__` to store variable attributes as well as constant ones if you provide a base class that your user can inherit from to "mark" a value as variable:

```
class PympleVariable(object):
    def __init__(self, container):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Pymple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__('_values', {})

    def register(self, key, value, constant=False):
        if constant:
            self._value[key] = lambda c: value
        else:
            self._value[key] = value

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        try:
            variable = issubclass(value, PympleVariable)
        except TypeError:
            variable = False

        self.register(key, value, not variable)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key not in self._values:
            raise AttributeError("'{}' is not registered.".format(key))

        return self._values[key](self)
```

So you can write:

```
class email(PympleVariable):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.mail = "{c.name}.{c.lastname}@{c.domain}".format(c=container)

    def __call__(self):
        return '[{}] {}'.format(time.time(), self.mail)

container = Pymple()
container.name = 'spam'
container.lastname = 'eggs'
container.domain = 'bacon'
container.frozen_email = email(container)
container.name = 'foo'
container.email = email
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
container.domain = 'example.org'
print(container.frozen_email())
print(container.email())
```

and get a pretty nice interface.

Comment: Thank you so much.

I'll not take the `PympleVariable` thing though, as I think it goes back into being unnecessarily complicated again. But I'm definitely taking the tip on using `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`

Comment: My bad, I meant to mark as answer right after leaving the comment.

Comment: Actually with this code you hit a recursion error in `__getattr__` when doing `if key not in self._values:`

Comment: @PauloPhagula Why so ? `self._values` is perfectly defined so won't trigger `__getattr__` again.

Comment: So instead of `def __init__: self._values = {}` it should be `def __init__ (self): self.__dict__['_values'] = {}` Because `__setattr__` is always called every time we do something like `self.foo = bar` and `__getattr__` every time we want to get the value a property like `self._value` which is being done in `if key not in self._values:`.

Comment: @PauloPhagula My bad, didn't though of it. You can use `super().__setattr__('_values', {})` in `__init__`.

Comment: @PauloPhagula Also note that `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute does not already exist on the instance. So `self._values` does not recurse into calling `__getattr__` again. It is `__getattribute__` that is called each time.

Comment: You're right. So, in the end, there are 2 things I want you to notice, 1st I'm not taking the `PimpleVariable` part, I want to keep it simple and avoid forcing people to create child classes or more complicated object graphs. 2nd, I'm adding the `callable` check in `__setattr__` and if value is callable I register as _variable_ otherwise as _constant_. I believe there'll be very few cases where people will want to register functions  in the IoC -- in which case an option is still left open for them by using the `register` method explicitly.

Comment: So, I had taken this code, made a github repo. And then when I was publishing on pypi I got a name conflict... There's already a library name pymple. It's based on the same project, and uses a syntax similar to this (register, resolve). The only difference it that it only supports python3.4+, since it uses the new type hints to infer the kind of dependencies to create. Just dropping the link here for anyone else looking for it: [https://github.com/BernhardPosselt/pymple](https://github.com/BernhardPosselt/pymple). I'll rename the library into something else to avoid conflict and republish.

Answer (score 1):

There are not much of things to review. I don't really like a way you are going to call sum and multiply.  But I think this is just an example.
However few things here.

Remove `__ini__` from `Sum` since it's not used and does nothing.

Instead of `not key in` use `key not in`